# Can not redeclare class, but it isn't declared

Tags: php, class, declaration, iis-8

I have some strange behavior in declaring a Class. `PHP` let me not declare a Class, because it is thinking it is already declared.

I double and tripple checked the output of `get_declared_classes()` and it is definitve not declared.

So I wrote a little Test:

```
namespace ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Login\PublicBackend\Main;

use ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Base\PresentationModel;


$classname = 'ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Login\PublicBackend\Main\Model';
if (class_exists($classname)) {
    return;
}

var_dump(class_exists($classname));


class Model extends PresentationModel {

}

var_dump(class_exists($classname));
```

The Output:

> bool(false) bool(true)
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Login\PublicBackend\Main\Model
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dev\Library\Presentation\Component\Login\PublicBackend\Main\Model.php
>   on line 21

I also double checked that there is a Unique `Model` in the Namespace `ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Login\PublicBackend\Main\`.

If it would be a coding error I would expecting  `bool(false) bool(true) bool(true)`. Also I would expexting the `return` statement would return, in that case.

This is my configuration:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS `8.5.9600.16384`
- PHP `5.5.10`

I also tried to reset the Server Process using `iisreset`, since I have had great success in the past, having strange problems.

So where is my Error? How can I declare my Class?

Comment: try to remove this `use ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Base\PresentationModel;` and add directly in the extend `class Model extends ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Base\PresentationModel` .

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump(class_exists('Model'))` instead of the full class name? Is there a `Model` class declared in the `PresentationModel`, i.e. does that extend `Model`?

Comment: I get `bool(false) bool(false)` if I replace it with `class_exists($classname)` with `class_exists('Model')` @Styphon

Comment: @Styphon `class_exists('Model')` literally checks if the class `\Model` exists. Class names passed as strings are always FQN, they do not resolve relative to the current namespace.

Comment: @deceze New one for me, didn't realise that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: By sure you should have another Mode.php class inside `ConversioIt\Cms\Library\Core\Presentation\Component\Login\PublicBackend\Main` no other explain. That is the framework you are using?

Comment: Christian, is line 21 really the `class Model` line in the file referred to above? It's not line 21 in this pasted code snippet, so there's obviously *some* discrepancy there. Sure you don't have some trailing code somewhere which *does* try to redeclare that class?

Comment: @deceze yes it is. I have removed some german comments before posting. `PHP DOC` makes files much bigger :D. `Line 21` basicly it the closing `}` of the Class. @albanx no, I have no other `Model.php` there. As already written, i have checked `get_declared_classes()`, and the error is thrown at exact the file I have posted. Its my own Codebase, no Framework.